# SubSonic Update 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: subsonic

is there any list of known problems about updating 2.1 to 2.2?

Where do I have to look at,
which methods/classes have ben changed?

Regards,

Martin

Answer (score 1):

The change list is here:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-22-released/

The issue list is here, this also covers SubSonic 3 though:

http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/issues/list